# Generate well-formatted Flask form output with tabulation and new lines

Tags: python, flask

I'm trying to create a web-app that will generate templated code for use on a separate program.  I want to produce a well-structured form message upon submission that incorporates tabs and new lines.

This is the current iteration of the code:

```
from flask import Flask, render_template
from flask_bootstrap import Bootstrap
from flask_wtf import FlaskForm
from wtforms import StringField, SubmitField
from wtforms.validators import Required

app = Flask(__name__)
# Flask-WTF requires an enryption key - the string can be anything
app.config['SECRET_KEY'] = 'some?bamboozle#string-foobar'
# Flask-Bootstrap requires this line
Bootstrap(app)
# this turns file-serving to static, using Bootstrap files installed in env
# instead of using a CDN
app.config['BOOTSTRAP_SERVE_LOCAL'] = True

# with Flask-WTF, each web form is represented by a class
# "NameForm" can change; "(FlaskForm)" cannot
# see the route for "/" and "index.html" to see how this is used
class NameForm(FlaskForm):
    group_name = StringField('Which is the name of the group label?', validators=[Required()])
    question = StringField('What is the question?', validators=[Required()])
    answer = StringField('What is the answer?', validators=[Required()])
    c1 = StringField('What is the first answer choice?', validators=[Required()])
    c2 = StringField('What is the second answer choice?', validators=[Required()])
    c3 = StringField('What is the third answer choice?', validators=[Required()])
    c4 = StringField('What is the fourth answer choice?', validators=[Required()])

    submit = SubmitField('Submit')

# all Flask routes below

# two decorators using the same function
@app.route('/', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
@app.route('/hello.html', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def hello():
    # you must tell the variable 'form' what you named the class, above
    # 'form' is the variable name used in this template: index.html
    form = NameForm()
    message = ""
    if form.validate_on_submit():
        message = f"""
            *group: {form.group_name.data}
            \t*program: Progress_Increment
            \t*question: {form.question.data}
            \t\t*shuffle
            \t\t{form.c1.data}
            \t\t{form.c2.data}
            \t\t{form.c3.data}
            \t\t{form.c4.data}
            \t\t*save: {form.group_name.data}_q1
            \t\t-- *countdown: 30.seconds
            \t\t*throwaway
            \t>> {form.group_name.data}_answer = "{form.answer.data}"

            \t*program: Progress_Increment
            \t*question: For the previous question, how confident are you that the answer you selected is reasonably close to the correct answer?
            \t\t*type: slider
            \t\t*before: 0% confident
            \t\t*after: 100% confident
            \t\t*min: 0
            \t\t*max: 100
            \t\t*save: {form.group_name.data}_confidence
            \t\t-- *countdown: 30.seconds
            \t\t*throwaway

            \t*program: Progress_Increment
            \t*question: Is it important to you that your answer is reasonably close to the correct answer? That is, is this a topic where you would care about being wrong or right?
            \t\t*type: slider
            \t\tDon't care at all
            \t\tCare a little
            \t\tCare somewhat
            \t\tCare somewhat strongly
            \t\tCare strongly
            \t\t*before: Don't care at all
            \t\t*after: Care strongly 
            \t\t*save: {form.group_name.data}_importance
            \t\t-- *countdown: 30.seconds
            \t\t*throwaway
            """


    # notice that we don't need to pass name or names to the template
    return render_template('hello.html', form=form, message=message)

# keep this as is
if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(debug=True)
```

And the .html file looks like this

```
{% extends 'bootstrap/base.html' %}
{% import "bootstrap/wtf.html" as wtf %}

{% block styles %}
{{ super() }}
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="{{ url_for('static', filename='css/main.css') }}">
{% endblock %}


{% block title %}
Question Submission
{% endblock %}


{% block content %}

<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-xs-12">

      <h1>Question Generator Page</h1>

      <p class="lead">Please fill out the forms below</p>

      {{ wtf.quick_form(form) }}

      <p class="space-above"><strong>{{ message }}</strong></p>

    </div>
  </div>
</div>

{% endblock %}
```

I want the output, when the form is submitted, to preserve the built-in tabulation that is embedded in the message.  I assume this will require some processing in the .html file, but I'm not sure the right way to go about doing this.

Any thoughts?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The CSS [`white-space`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/white-space) property can preserve spaces, tabs, etc. in the HTML. `pre` or `pre-wrap` seem appropriate for this situation:

> `pre`
>
> Sequences of white space are preserved. Lines are only broken at
>   newline characters in the source and at <br> elements.
>
> `pre-wrap`
>
> Sequences of white space are preserved. Lines are broken at newline
>   characters, at <br>, and as necessary to fill line boxes.

Wrap the content in an appropriate element (e.g. `div`), and add the style to that:

```
<p class="space-above" style="white-space: pre-wrap"><strong>{{ message }}</strong></p>
```

Note: A `style` attribute does the job here, but external stylesheets are generally preferred.

Comment: Thanks!  Apologies, but I'm a new to web programming.  How would I implement this in the .html file? 

I tried `<pre> {{ wtf.quick_form(form) }}</pre>`

To no avail